# User input in Hashsets for later comparison

Tags: java

I am trying to take in the user inputs into a Hashset and I need to use the hash set objects for element comparison later. How can I do this? Below is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GemStones{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();      
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
            String str = in.next();
            for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
                char c = str.charAt(j);
                set.add(c);
            }
        }
        in.close();                         
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use your hashset for later comparison then ideally you need to store it in instance variable. Also please point out exactly what is that you are not able to do by pointing in your code

Comment: Sure Anand. Here if user inputs 3 char strings, how can I get three separate set objects to manipulate later. can you clarify a little bit on how can I store in instance variable? Basic question, since I started learning late..:P

Comment: Please investigate arrays and lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance variable this way by declaring the set outside your method at class level. If you want to later get the contents of this set and modify from a different class

```
public class GemStones{

    private HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();     


    public HashSet<Character> getSet() {
        return set;
    }

    public void setSet(HashSet<Character> set) {
        this.set = set;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      GemStones stoneObj = new GemStones();
      .......
       HashSet set = stoneObj.getSet();
       set.add(c)
     ......

      ......


....

    }
```

This gives you an outline and you need to check further on instance and local varaibles and how to access objects and naming conventions to make your code better.